# How to set a col val based on 2 other cols in a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

In mySql I'm trying to set the value of a column (`total`) based on the values of 2 other columns of the same table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9c27a/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_total` (
    `order_total_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `value` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`order_total_id`),
    KEY `order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=244 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `order_total` (`order_total_id`, `order_id`, `code`, `title`, `value`, `sort_order`) VALUES
(241, 80, 'sub_total', 'Sub-Total', '400.0000', 1),
(242, 80, 'shipping', 'Free Shipping', '10.0000', 3),
(243, 80, 'total', 'Total', '0', 9);
```

I tried such a code which works in local mySql, but I thought maybe there is a better way to do it.

```
UPDATE order_total ot 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, value
    FROM order_total
        WHERE code = 'sub_total'
    GROUP BY order_id
) o ON ot.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, value
    FROM order_total
        WHERE code = 'shipping'
    GROUP BY order_id
) o2 ON ot.order_id = o2.order_id
SET ot.value = o.value + o2.value 
WHERE ot.code = 'total' AND ot.order_id = 80
```

How to do it more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the total using one query as follows:

```
update order_total ot 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT order_id, sum(value) value
   FROM order_total
   WHERE code = 'sub_total' or code= 'shipping'
   GROUP BY order_id
) o ON ot.order_id = o.order_id
SET ot.value = o.value
WHERE ot.code = 'total' AND ot.order_id = 80;
```

Comment: Your answer is also very nice and works perfect. Thanks a lot. Which one is more efficient in your mind?

Comment: This is is better answer as it has less complexity. IMHO

Comment: I already marked previous answer as correct! What should I do now!? :-|

Comment: You can alway u mark it, and mark another one, if you want to

Comment: This is the better answer, barring some possible duplication in your data, which I don't think is the case +1.  But see my answer for caveats.

Answer (score 2):

Your current query is technically invalid, because the subqueries are selecting non aggregate columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  But we can fix this, and make the query more succinct, by using conditional aggregation to find the subtotal and shipping values for each order:

```
UPDATE order_total ot 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        order_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'sub_total' THEN value END) AS sub_value,
        MAX(CASE WHEN code = 'shipping'  THEN value END) AS shipping_value,
    FROM order_total
    GROUP BY order_id
) o
    ON ot.order_id = o.order_id
SET ot.value = o.sub_value + o.shipping_value
WHERE
    ot.code = 'total' AND
    ot.order_id = 80;
```

For this particular problem, the accepted answer is the way to go.  But if you wanted something other than the sum, then it would not work.  My answer would let you do something like this:

```
SET ot.value = o.sub_value + 2*o.shipping_value
```

That is, if we wanted to give the shipping value a weight of 2, this answer allows for this to be easily done.

Comment: I think there should be a simple solution then this. Let me try to find that

Comment: @Tim :-D I'm waiting for SO to let me do it. 1 min is left!

Comment: @Tim, if you don't mind, I'm going to mark `Md`'s answer as correct, because it's less complex. Is it OK?